# Keeping the rows with less than bigger than a real number in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a large data sets and the variable includes different format
such as 2, 3, >2, <4, " I go <> to school". " I need to < be there".

How can I make a subset of the data sets which just includes the rows such as < 2 or > 10 (less than or bigger than a number)?

```
Subject   Result
1           3
2           4
3           <4
4           <3
5          I need to go to school<>
6          I need to <> be there
7          2.3 need to be< there
```

Comment: Please show a small example using `dput` and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[grep("^\\s*[<>][0-9]+$", df$variable),]
```

This will produce a subset of `df` with all rows where the data in column `variable` is in the format of a number preceded by < or >, and with nothing but numbers after it.

I added `\\s*` because it seems from your data that some cases have padding spaces before the number, so this will remove any such spaces.

Comment: Thanks so much, do you have any idea for this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733359/keeping-specific-rows-with-grep-function