# Keeping specific rows with grep function

Tags: regex, replace

I have a large data sets and the variable includes different format

```
Subject   Result
1           3
2           4
3          <4
4          <3
5          I need to go to school<>
6          I need to <> be there
7          2.3 need to be< there
8          <.3
9          .<9
10         ..<9
11         >3 need to go to school
12         <16.1
13         <5.0
```

I just want to keep the rows which include the "< number" or "> number" and not the rows with the text format (**forexample, I want to exclude >3 need to school, I need to go to school <>**). The problem is that some records are something like .<3, ..<9, >9., >:9. So how can I remove ".","..",":" from the data set and then keep the rows with "< a number" notation. How can I use "grep" function?
 Again, I just want to keep the following rows

```
    Subject   Result
>     3          <4
>     4          <3
>     8          <.3
>     9          .<9
>     10         ..<9
>     12         <16.1
>     13         <5.0
```

Comment: It's important when asking about regex (or anything, really) to be explicit about the language you're using -- preferably also to include a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply apply two greps, one to find the "<>" keys, and then one to eliminate fields with characters:

> grep "[><]" | grep -v "[A-Za-z]"

If you want to be pedantic, you can also apply another grep to find those with numbers

> grep "[><]" | grep -v "[A-Za-z]" | grep "[0-9]"

"grep **-v**" means match and don't return, by the way.

Comment: thanks so much. I could not run the code. Could please run the code on the example and post the complete codes

Comment: There are two ways, if it's in a file called "file.txt" then run the command like this *cat file.txt | grep "[><]" | grep -v "[A-Za-z]" | grep "[0-9]"* OR  *grep "[><]" file.txt | grep -v "[A-Za-z]" | grep "[0-9]"*

Comment: I run  A<-Data$Result| grep "[><]" | grep -v "[A-Za-z]" | grep "[0-9]" and I got the error.

Comment: What environment are you in? I am discussing it from a bash shell perspective. If you can run bash commands from your environment then my code will be helpful.

Comment: You're in R, I'm guessing. Try this: A<-Data$Result[!grepl("[A-Za-z]", Data$Result) & grepl("[><]",Data$Result) & grepl("[0-9]",Data$Result)]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're certain that [.,:;] are the only problematic punctuation:

```
df$Result<-gsub("[.,;:]","", df$Result) # remove any cases of [.,;:] from your results column
df[grep("^\\s*[<>][0-9]+$", df$Result),] # find all cases of numbers preceded by < or >  (with possible spaces) and succeeded by nothing else.
```